# For any countably infinite set $M$, the set of all countably infinite subsets of $M$, whose complement is countably infinite is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $M$ be any countably infinite set.

Let $X_{M}$:=$\{A\in M:|A|<\aleph_{0}\}$
(The set of all finite subsets of $M$)
and

let $Y_{M}$:=$\{B\in M:B=M\backslash A, A\in X_{M}\}$
(The set of all countably infite subsets of $M$, whose complement is finite)
and

let $Z_{M}$:=$\{C\in M:|C|=|M\backslash C|=\aleph_{0}\}$.
(The set of all countably infite subsets of $M$, whose complement is countably infinite).

If $f$ is a function from $X_{M}$ to $Y_{M}$, such that $f(T):=M\backslash T$, then $f$ is bijective.

($\because$ If $f(U)=f(W)\implies M\backslash U=M\backslash W\implies U=W \implies f$ is one-one.

If $S\in Y_{M}$, then by definiton of $Y_{M}$, $M\backslash S \in X_{M}$, also $f(M\backslash S)=M\backslash (M\backslash S)=S \implies f$ is onto.)

Thus, $|X_{M}|=|Y_{M}|=\aleph_{0}$ and also we have $X_{M} \cup Y_{M} \cup Z_{M}=P(M)$ and $X_{M} \cap Y_{M} \cap Z_{M}=\varnothing \implies |Z_{M}|>\aleph_{0}$

Based, on this can we say that for any countably infinite set $M$, its power set $P(M)$is uncountable due to the existence of $Z_{M}$?

Comment: You haven't shown anything about $Z_M$, not even that it's nonempty (it is), so how would it imply anything about the power set?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thats doable. Since $|M|=\aleph_{0}$, we can write $M$ as $M=\{m_{i}:i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Consider $M_{E}:=\{m_{j}:j \text{ is even }\}$, then this set is an element of $Z_{M}$ as $M\backslash M_{E}=\{m_{k}:\text{ k is odd }\}$ is countably infinite. Thus, $Z_{M}$ is non-empty.

Comment: @KevinShenoy the problem isn't that you specifically haven't shown $Z_M$ is nonempty. It's that your proof doesn't show it is uncountable, as that doesn't follow from the properties of $X_M$ and $Y_M$ that you have described, and you haven't shown anything about $Z_M$ directly. It's not clear why you think $X_M∩Y_M∩Z_M$ being empty means $Z_M$ is uncountable.

Comment: Because $X_{M},Y_{M}$ are countably infinite and $X_{M} \cup Y_{M} \cup Z_{M}=P(M)$. If $Z_{M}$ is countable, then  $P(M)$ will turn out to be countable, a contradiction

Comment: If your purpose here is to deduce what part of $P(M)$ is responsible for $P(M)$ being uncountable, rather than to prove that $P(M)$ is uncountable, then you've named the question very misleadingly.

Comment: Agreed. I will make the needed correction.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your argument, no.

You're concluding that $Z_M$ is uncountable because the other two parts of the power set are countable. But unless you already know that $\mathcal P(M)$ is uncountable, why would that be true? If we divide $\Bbb Q$, the rational numbers, into the positive integers, the negative integers, and all the rest of them rational numbers, the first two parts are easily countable, can we conclude that the third part is uncountable? No.

If, however, your argument would have been a diagonalisation argument of some sort, or a direct argument that $Z_M$ is uncountable, then you can say that $\mathcal P(M)$ is uncountable, because you'd shown that it has an uncountable subset.

Comment: By Cantor's Theorm, the cardinality of the power set of any set is strictly greater than that of the given set. Thus, $P(M)$ is already uncountable, even before $Z_{M}$ is defined. But, I was drawing a conclusion on why exactly does $P(M)$ become uncountable.

Comment: Yes. But you are asking "Can I conclude that ...", and the answer is no. Your argument would be circular. What you are in fact concluding is that *because* $\mathcal P(M)$ is uncountable due to Cantor's theorem, the set $Z_M$ is also uncountable.

Comment: But, the disjoint union of $X_{M}$, $Y_{M}$, $Z_{M}$ is equal to $P(M)$, and I already showed that $X_{M},Y_{M}$ are countably infinite. Thus, $Z_{M}$ has to be uncountable. Provided we know $P(M)$ is uncountable.(due to Cantor's Theorem).

Comment: Yes. That is what I said, and that's fine. But you asked about concluding that $\mathcal P(M)$ is uncountable based on the argument that $Z_M$ is uncountable due to the fact that $\mathcal P(M)$ is uncountable, and I hope you can see why that would be circular.

Comment: I needed to mention in my query that I know that $P(M)$ is uncountable. But as to why is it so, $Z_{M}$ is responsible for it. As in when we consider $\mathbb{N}$ and consider the set of all countably infinite subsets of it(relating it to $P(\mathbb{N}$), and proving its uncountable. We can make a further bifurcation in it, removing all those whose complement is finite
 Thus, we are just left with the subsets whose complement is countably infinite

Comment: Look, we're going in circles here. I can only answer to the question you've asked. And you've asked it in a specific way. Part of the training as a mathematician is to know how to phrase your questions in a way that conveys your meaningful without ambiguity and without people misnuderstanding you (especially in text). Consider this to be a practical lesson.

Comment: I agree that I phrased my question incorrectly. I am still learning, not really  in training to be associated to a certain profession yet.